# Is there a way to count all open chrome windows with python?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I'm using chrome, and I've been trying to find a way to count open windows with python, I know it can be done with selenium but it only counts the open windows in the webdriver, is there any way to do it in "normal" chrome? What I need is the number of the total opened windows.